# Adding styles for a raster in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, raster, style

I have a PostgreSQL/PostGIS database located on a server.
I have added shapefiles (with the "PostGIS shapefile import/export manager") and raster (with "raster2pgsql"). It works well.

However, when I try to save layer styles in this database (through QGIS) it works well for shapefiles but for raster it is only possible to save the style on local machine in a *.qml or *.sld file (and therefore not in PostgreSQL as it can be done for shapefiles and stored in layer_styles).

Is there a way to save style for rasters in PostgreSQL/PostGIS ?
(I am a rookie with PostgreSQL/PostGIS).

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible like the ease of vector styles saved in the postgres layer_styles table. But there are some alternatives - testet in QGIS 3.20.3:

1.
Saving the raster style in QGIS as default (Layer properties > Style button > Save As Default) will save the style as a QML string in a sqlite database placed here: C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\qgis.qmldb. Loading the raster from PostGIS will automatically load the style. This will only work on the computer saving the style.

2.
Save the QGIS project into Postgres (Project > Save To > PostgreSQL...). Loading the project from the db will load the raster style for any raster layer.

**UPDATE**

If your raster has one band you can convert it to RGB (three bands). This will render the raster with the correct style when loaded from PostGIS to QGIS:

Step 1: Save the 1-band raster as rgb using QGIS export

[image]

Step 2: Load to PostGIS using raster2pgsql